# Break a row of words into word groups in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have some text that I would like to break down into two, three, or even four words at a time.  I'm trying to pull meaningful phrases.

I have used `split` and `explode` to retrieve what I need, but I would like to have the row broken into two or three words at a time. This is what I have so far, which only breaks the row into one word at a time.

```
select explode(a.text) text
from (select split(text," ") text
      from table abc
      where id = 123
      and date = 2019-08-16
     ) a
```

The Output I get:

```
text
----
thank 
you 
for 
calling
your
tv
is
not
working
?
```

I would like an output like this:

```
text
----
Thank you 
for calling 
your tv
is not
working?
```

or something like this:

```
text
----
thank you for calling
your
tv is not working
?
```

Comment: you will have to define your own UDF function for that - hive is not that smart

Comment: Look at this answer please: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52802766/2700344 - breaking into 2-grams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS db.test_string
(
text string
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS orc
;

INSERT INTO TABLE db.test_string VALUES
('thank you for calling your tv is not working ?');
```

below is query:

```
select k,s from db.test_string
lateral view posexplode(split(text,' ')) pe as i,s
lateral view posexplode(split(text,' ')) ne as j,k
where ne.j=pe.i-1
and ne.j%2==0
;

thank   you
for     calling
your    tv
is      not
working ?
Time taken: 0.248 seconds, Fetched: 5 row(s)
```

add above logic to your actual table with where clause and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Hi Vikrant:  Thanks for the response.  Unfortunately my version of Hive errors on the section lateral view posexplode(split(text,' ') pe as i,s    lateral view posexplode(split(text,' ') pe as j,k.  It's erroring on the i,s and j,k.  It will not accept an alias with a comma. Likewise,my version of Hive doesn't recognize posexplode, only explode.I can split, explode, and use lateral view, I just can't end up with word groups instead of single words.

Comment: Did u ran the same query? which hive version you are using?

Comment: Not sure what error you are facing but can see a ) is missing in the code.. above comment section.

Comment: Hi Vikrant:  I tried it again.  I must have done something wrong earlier.  This works!  Many thanks.  This answers my question.