# Hive - Analyzing Long Strings for commonalities

Tags: hive, hiveql

I'm new to hive and looking for some help. I'm looking to obtain the different combinations of phrases within a string. For example, if the string was "Today was a good day." I would want the results of my query to be the unique pairs in order within the string. So something like:
"Today was"
"was a"
"a good"
"good day"

Then I want to know the the combinations of every 3 words. So the result would be:
"Today was a"
"was a good"
"a good day"

Then every 4 words, etc.

Then finish with the count of the different combinations.

Any ideas? Thank you!

create table memo_test_2
select memo_field as sentence, words.pos, words.word
  from main_memo_table
        lateral view posexplode(split(memo_field, '[ ,]+')) words as pos, word;

create table memo_test_3
select s1.sentence, collect_set(concat_ws(' ',s1.word, s2.word)) as ngrams 
      from memo_test_2 s1 
           inner join memo_test_2 s2 on s1.sentence=s2.sentence and s1.pos+1=s2.pos
group by s1.sentence;

create table memo_test_4
select word, count(1) as count 
from (select explode(ngrams) as word
from memo_test_3) w
group by word

Comment: It sounds like you want to count the number combinations of contiguous words from 2 to _n_-1 in a string of length _n_. What have you tried so far and what was the result?

Comment: Thanks Mick, yeah that sounds about right. I'm a bit over my head, but was able to get the below to run. It appears to work and gives me the counts of contiguous word pairs. Now would like to try to do the contiguous 3 words, 4 words, etc. I'm sure there is probably a more efficient way...

Comment: create table memo_test_2
select memo_field as sentence, words.pos, words.word
  from main_memo_table
        lateral view posexplode(split(memo_field, '[ ,]+')) words as pos, word;

create table memo_test_3
select s1.sentence, collect_set(concat_ws(' ',s1.word, s2.word)) as ngrams 
      from memo_test_2 s1 
           inner join memo_test_2 s2 on s1.sentence=s2.sentence and s1.pos+1=s2.pos              
group by s1.sentence;
create table memo_test_4
select word, count(1) as count 
from (select explode(ngrams) as word
from memo_test_3) w
group by word

Comment: Read this answer "How to generate all n-grams in Hive" https://stackoverflow.com/a/52802766/2700344